# Excel VBA to copy cell value if > 0 to cell to the left

Tags: vba, excel, copy

In **Column W** I have **BALANCE2** values &
In **Column X** I have **BALANCE3** values

I need to move the values **from BALANCE3 (which are greater than zero) to overwrite the corresponding cell in BALANCE2** so that I have one total list of payments.

Can anyone help to work with this one? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: WELCOME to stackoverflow. Actually, you should post some piece of code what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Public Sub overwriteValues()

    Dim row As Integer

    'Set start row
    row = 1

    With Sheets("sheetname")

        'Loop until column X cell is blank
        'You can modify column if you want other
        Do While .Range("X" & row) <> ""

            If .Range("X" & row) > 0 Then

                .Range("W" & row) = .Range("X" & row)

            End If

            'Increase row
            row = row + 1

        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that this code assumes that column `X` is always populated, and empty row would stop the script

Comment: Yes, I don't know his requirement for breaking looping. So, I did it like this. If he has some issues with this code, I will modify for that. If the answer is work, mark as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not use a macro for this**

Just use excel's built in `IF`, for example, assuming `BALANCE2` is column `W` and `BALANCE3` is column `X`, write in cell `Z1`

`=IF(X1>0,X1,W1)`

And then drag it down to the entire column, cut and paste column `Z` into column `W`, and you got your "overwrite" without writing macro code

Comment: Hi, sorry all other cells contain values as well so I would rather run this as a macro if possible?  Thanks for answering so swiftly.

Comment: All other cells ?, there's gotta be a column name that you are not using (e.g. `ZZ`)

Comment: Saying do not use a macro for this is not actually a very helpful answer.

We do not know if this is a one off task or if in fact it would be something needed on a regular basis for example a monthly report. If it is to be used on a regular basis then a macro may well be the better way of doing it.